# How to Make an Image not Resize Because of Rotating it (in JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a method that rotates an image and uses the drawImage method to display it onto a canvas. However, when rotating the image, the image shrinks and grows because the width and height change (say you rotate a square, the width and height of the image changes). Here is the method:

```
public void rotateImage(GraphicsContext gc, double speed) {
    erase(gc);  // erases the previous image
    imgView.setRotate(imgView.getRotate() + speed);
    SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
    params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    image = imgView.snapshot(params, null);
    gc.drawImage(image, pos.x, pos.y, width, height);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, and I can post the rest of the code if needed.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? And maybe you'd have more success setting [the transform](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setTransform(javafx.scene.transform.Affine)) of the `GraphicsContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A snapshot with the provided parameters uses the dimensions of the node in the parent to determine the size of the image. Rotating an image yields dimensions different to those of the original image in most cases. In those cases the snapshot is bigger than the original image. (Consider a square image rotated by 45°; The width and height of the rotated image is the size of the diagonal of the original image, i.e. larger by a factor of `sqrt(2) = 1.41...`).

Since `drawImage` scales the drawn image to fit into a rectangle of size `width x height`, the snapshot that is larger than this size is scaled down.

Use the transforms of the `GraphicsContext` instead to avoid creating a new `Image` instance with each call of the method and avoid scaling the image.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image image = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/240px-Smiley.svg.png");
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
    GraphicsContext context = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    Slider slider = new Slider(0, 360, 0);
    Button btn = new Button("draw");
    VBox root = new VBox(canvas, slider, btn);


    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        context.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        double posX = 200;
        double posY = 150;

        context.save();

        // apply transformation that puts makes (posX, posY) the point
        // where (0,0) is drawn and rotate
        context.translate(posX, posY);
        context.rotate(slider.getValue());

        // draw with center at (0, 0)
        context.drawImage(image, -image.getWidth()/2, -image.getHeight()/2);

        // undo transformations
        context.restore();
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. However, the problem is that I cannot just rotate the entire canvas as there are other things on it as well, the image is only one of the objects on it. Maybe there is a way I could directly change the image, however?

Comment: @JohnA. You are not "rotating the entire canvas". `save()` saves the current state of the transforms and `restore()` undoes all changes done since the `save()` call. You can add additional drawing operations before the `save()` call or after the `restore()` call in my sample code; those operations are not affected by the  transformation (also the rotation does not accumulate pressing the button mulitple times which should be another indicator).

Comment: Okay, it works now, but how would I accumulate the rotation by pressing the button multiple times? (as I'm trying to make a spinning image that rotates with a certain speed)

Comment: The `ImageView.rotate` property can simply be replaced with a field used to store this data...